# Collapse in the first if the latest closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am taking bootstrap3's collapse tools. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

but I want that if all closed, the first div should open again, so that no spare space will be there if all are closed.

this is what i tried, but this is working only once and for the second time, it is not opening the first. any ideas why?

```
 $(function(){
   $('#four').on('click', function () {
      var four_class = $('#collapseFour').attr("class");
      if(four_class=="panel-collapse in"){
        $('#collapseOne').collapse();
      }
   });
 });
```

my fourth content

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
       <a class="accordion-toggle lead" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFour" id="four">
       Locations eintragen
        </a>
      </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">
         fourth content                       
    </div>
  </div>                            
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to watch the `hidden.bs.collapse` event which is broadcast when a panel has closed.

In there you check if the number of panels is equal to the number of closed panels and if so open the first one..

```
$('#accordion').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function (item) {
    // after closing check if any is still open
    var self = $(this),
        collapsed = self.find('.collapsed'),
        all = self.find('.panel-title'),
        allClosed = collapsed.length === all.length;

    if (allClosed){
        setTimeout(function(){
            self.find('.panel-collapse').first().collapse('show');
            }, 10);
    }
})
```